# Не могу приконнектиться к psql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, jetbrains, datagrip

Из консоли замечательно получается приконнектиться к серверу *postgres*. Делаю это с рутовым паролем так:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
```

При этом, когда пытаюсь проделать аналогичный трюк через DataGrip, ничего не выходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В связи с этим 4 вопроса:

- Может ли быть так, что *psql* не висит ни накаком порту, а во время того, как я захожу из консоли, коннекта не происходит какие-то ещё действия?
- Как понять, на каком порту висит *psql*?
- Можно ли как-нибудь пингануть *psql*?
- В чём проблема с DataGrip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`psql` - это клиент к PostgreSQL. Поэтому он совершенно точно не висит ни на каком порту и ни на какие пинги не отвечает, это всего лишь консольный клиент.

PostgreSQL - это серверная база. И спрашиваете вы видимо именно про подключение к ней.

> когда пытаюсь проделать аналогичный трюк через DataGrip

Вы уверены, что аналогичный? А где `sudo`? Текст ошибки совершенно точно говорит, что база вас услышала и считает указанный вами пароль неверным. В случае недоступности БД ответ был бы иным. Есть так же большая вероятность того, что `localhost` ваш клиент понимает как подключение через TCP/IP, а не через unixsock.

`psql` же подключаться успешно может по разным причинам. Основная и наиболее вероятная - он подключается через unixsock и в `pg_hba.conf` базы найдено подходящее правило с peer аутентификацией, которая не запрашивают пароль для подключения, а проверяет вместо этого имя пользователя ОС. Тогда как при подключении через TCP/IP используется другое правило, вероятно с md5 типом аутентификации - который пароль запрашивает и проверяет.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что psql -- это клиент. Плохо написал. Да, разумеется, спрашиваю про подключение к бд. Да, я уверне, что ввожу аналогичный пароль. Мне удалось приконектиться к БД (в *datagrip*) путём создания другого юзера через клиента *psql*.

Comment: Аналогичный с чем?

Comment: аналогичный с тем, что ввожу в консоли

Comment: а в консоли вводите пароль sudo? Это не тот и не имеет никакого отношения к базе. Или после sudo вас уже psql спрашивает пароль?

Comment: Нет, после sudo пароль не спрашивается.

Comment: Значит вы вводите не тот пароль. Возможно у postgres вообще нет пароля и парольного входа соответственно (пользователя в базе! не имеет отношения к пользователям ОС!). Это частая ситуация для кластера после установки.

Comment: Я пробовал с разными паролями, в том числе и без пароля. Это не помогает.

Comment: Повторюсь: возможно у postgres в вашей базе вовсе нет пароля. Если пароля нет, но по pg_hba требуется парольная аутентификация - вы её не пройдёте какой бы пароль вы не писали. Да, запрос пароля будет, это сделано специально. А в ответ - всегда неверный пароль.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за то, что разжевали и положили в рот

Comment: Проверьте, настроен ли сервер для внешних подключений
https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html