# Не могу запустить через командную строку psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда пытаюсь запустить psql через командную строку получаю: "'psql' не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.". В path уже добавил. Какие ещё есть варианты?

Answer (score 2):

Слишком мало информации, чтобы дать верный ответ.

Если терминал говорит, что исполняемый файл не найден, попробуйте удалить и заново установить postgresql:

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

Если проблема связана с ошибкой самого postgres, то, возможно, надо сначала настроить БД и пользователя. Для этого надо зайти под пользователем postgres, это можно сделать командой

```
sudo su postgres
```

А после зайти в psql и выполнить необходимые настройки

```
psql
> CREATE DATABASE db_name;
> CREATE USER user1;
> ALTER DATABASE db_name OWNER user1;
```

Это пока всё, что приходит мне в голову.

UPD: Возможно Вам поможет ответ на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/875261/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-psql?rq=1)

Comment: У топикстартера, насколько я могу судить, Windows (:

Comment: дада, именно он :)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica когда давался ответ, это было совершенно не очевидно :)